# What is the nth derivative of $\frac{x^a}{a^x}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is there a closed form solution for the $n$th derivative of the following function? $$f(x)=\frac{x^a}{a^x}$$

Using the quotient rule gives $$f'(x)=\frac{(ax^{a-1})a^x-x^a(a^x\ln a)}{(a^x)^2}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{(ax^{a-1})-x^a(\ln a)}{a^x}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac ax\cdot\frac{x^a}{a^x}-(\ln a)\frac{x^a}{a^x}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac axf(x)-(\ln a)f(x)$$

$$f'(x)=(\frac ax-\ln a)f(x)$$

Is there a way to use this equation to find the higher derivatives?

Edit: n is a natural number

Edit2: I think I can change the problem from a derivative to a series using @KevinDietrich 's answer.

If $p(x)=x^a$ then $p^{(n)}(x)= \frac{a!}{(a - n)!}\cdot x^{n}=n!{a \choose n}\cdot x^n$

If $q(x)=a^{-x}$ then  $q'(x)=(\ln a)a^{-x}\cdot (-1)=(-\ln a)a^{-x}=(-\ln a)q(x)$

$q'(x)=(-\ln a)q(x)$ implies that $q^{(n)}(x)=(-\ln a)^nq(x)=(-\ln a)^na^{-x}$

Since $f(x)=p(x)q(x)$, then by general Leibniz rule, $$f^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}p^{(n-k)}(x)q^{(k)}(x)$$

$$f^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}(n-k)!{a \choose n-k}\cdot x^{n-k}(-\ln a)^ka^{-x}$$

Does $a$ need to be a natural number and does this series have a closed form?

Comment: Is $n \in  \mathbb{N}$ then you can use [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) and [General Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule). You can also simply write $a^{x}$ or $x^{a}$ as a power series and use $\frac{\operatorname{d}^{n}}{\operatorname{d}x^{n}}x^{a} = \frac{a!}{(a - n)!} \cdot x^{n}$. Alternatively, using fractional differential operators would also work.

Comment: This might or might not help but some more calculation needs to be done after using this link https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=nth+derivative+of+exp%28g%28x%29%29

Comment: @userrandrand combined with https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=nth+derivative+of+%28alnx-xlna%29%5Em should reduce it to a series problem but I don't know how to input that in Wolfram

Comment: Use [Associated Laguerre polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLaguerrePolynomial.html) Rodrigues rule and $\frac{d^n f(ax)}{dx^n}=a^n f^{(n)}(ax)$ to get answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using General Leibniz rule (Higher Product rule) seems often easier than Higher Quotient rule.

$$x^a=e^{\ln(x)a}$$
$$\frac{1}{a^x}=e^{-\ln(a)x}$$

Let $(m)_n$ denote the Pochhammer symbol (rising factorial).

Using Faà di Bruno's formula (Higher Chain rule), we get:

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{\ln(x)a}=(a-n+1)_n\ x^{a-n},$$
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-\ln(a)x}=(-\ln(a))^ne^{-\ln(a)x}.$$

Using General Leibniz rule, we get:

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(f(x)\cdot g(x))=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}f(x)\cdot\frac{d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}}g(x).$$

So we get:

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{x^a}{a^x}=\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(e^{\ln(x)a}\cdot e^{-\ln(a)x}\right)$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(a-k+1)_k\ x^{a-k}(-\ln(a))^{n-k}e^{-\ln(a)x}$$
$$=a^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(a-k+1)_k\ (-\ln(a))^{n-k}x^{a-k}$$
$$=\frac{x^a}{a^x}(-\ln(a))^n\ {}_2F_0(-a,-n;\ ;-\frac{1}{x\ln(a)})$$

We see, $a$ doesn't need to be a natural number.

Answer (score 2):

Reading @mweiss's answer and writing $$f(x)=\frac{x^a}{a^x}=\frac{x^a}{e^{x\log(a)}}$$

$$f^{(n)}(x)=n!\,\binom{a}{n}\,\frac{x^a}{a^x}\,x^{-n}\,\,\, _1F_1(-n;-n+a+1;x \log (a))$$ where appears Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial (incomplete) answer:

From $$f'(x) = \left( \frac ax - \ln a \right)f(x)$$
we find (using the Product Rule):
$$\begin{aligned} f''(x) &= \left(-\frac {a}{x^2} \right)f(x) + \left( \frac ax - \ln a \right) f'(x) \\ &= \left(-\frac {a}{x^2} \right)f(x) + \left( \frac ax - \ln a \right)^2 f(x) \\ &= \left(\left(\frac ax - \ln a\right)^2- \frac{a}{x^2} \right) f(x) \end{aligned}$$

This suggests that the general form might be something like
$$f^{(n)}(x) = P_n\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)f(x)$$
where $P_n\left( \frac 1x \right)$ is an $n^{th}$ degree polynomial in $1/x$.  This is certainly the case for $n = 0, 1, 2$, with:
$$P_0\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 1$$
$$P_1\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \frac ax - \ln a$$
$$P_2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \left(\frac ax - \ln a\right)^2- \frac{a}{x^2}$$

We can find a recursive formula for finding the polynomials $P_n\left(\frac 1x \right)$ as follows:  assume that for some $k$,
$$f^{(k)}(x) = P_k\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)f(x)$$
Then the next derivative would be
$$\begin{aligned} f^{(k+1)}(x) &= \frac{d}{dx} \left( P_k\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)f(x) \right) \\ &= P_k'\left(\frac 1x \right)\left( -\frac{1}{x^2} \right)f(x) + P_k\left(\frac 1x \right) f'(x) \\ &= P_k'\left(\frac 1x \right)\left( -\frac{1}{x^2} \right)f(x) + P_k\left(\frac 1x \right)\left( \frac ax - \ln a \right)f(x) \\ &= \left(P_k'\left(\frac 1x \right)\left( -\frac{1}{x^2} \right) + P_k\left(\frac 1x \right)\left( \frac ax - \ln a \right) \right) f(x)  \end{aligned}$$

We can write this in a somewhat more convenient form if we introduce $u = 1/x$.  Then the recursive formula for the polynomials $P_n(u)$ is
$$\begin{aligned} P_{n+1}(u) &= P_n'\left(u \right)\left( -u^2 \right) + P_n\left(u \right)\left( au - \ln a \right)\\ &= auP_n(u) - u^2P'_n(u) - (\ln a)P_n(u) \end{aligned}$$

I don't know if there's a closed-form expression for $P_n(u)$ but this at least gives an algorithmic way to generate them with nothing more complicated than polynomial differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

With CAS:
$$\frac{\partial ^n}{\partial x^n}\frac{x^a}{a^x}=\\a^{-x} x^{a-n} \binom{a}{n} n! \, _1F_1(-n;1+a-n;x \ln (a))=\\a^{-x} x^{a-n} n! L_n^{a-n}(x \ln (a))=\\a^{-x}
   x^{a-n} n! \sum _{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k \binom{a}{-k+n} (x \ln (a))^k}{k!}$$

where $ L_n^{a-n}(x \ln (a))$ is generalized Laguerre polynomial.